# Shopify template: Stop background repeating (ajax?)

Tags: ajax, shopify

I'm trying to stop a background image repeating in a responsive shopify template, I am used to tinkering in basic code as best I can however this is way out of my skill range. I'm hoping that someone could help with what i'm hoping would be a very simple fix.. Sharing 2 sections of the code that seem to reference the area in which the image is repeating...
[repeating image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrNVK.jpg)

This..

```
//== Breadcrumbs
//
//##
$breadcrumb-padding-vertical:   50px;
$breadcrumb-padding-horizontal: 0px;
//** Breadcrumb background color
$breadcrumb-bg:                 $nocolor;
//** Breadcrumb text color
$breadcrumb-color:              $white;
//** Text color of current page in the breadcrumb
$breadcrumb-active-color:       $white;
//** Textual separator for between breadcrumb elements
$breadcrumb-separator:          "/";
```

And this..

```
//
// Breadcrumbs
// --------------------------------------------------

#breadcrumbs{
background-color:$breadcrumb-bg;
padding: $breadcrumb-padding-vertical $breadcrumb-padding-horizontal;
}
.breadcrumb {
text-align:center;
font-family: $font-family-tertiary;
//margin-bottom: $line-height-computed;
list-style: none;
background-color: $breadcrumb-bg;
text-transform:uppercase;
border-radius: $border-radius-base;
display:none;
> li {
display: inline-block;
a,span{
    font-size: $theme-font-size;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: $breadcrumb-color;
}
a{
  &:hover{
   span{
       color:$theme-color-secondary;
     } 
  }
}
+ li:before {
  content: "#{$breadcrumb-separator}"; // Unicode space added since inline-
block means non-collapsing white-space
  font-size: $theme-font-size;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: $breadcrumb-color;
}
}

> .active {
span{
    color: $breadcrumb-active-color;
}
color: $breadcrumb-active-color;
}
}
//
```